# How to sort search results on multiple fields using a weighting function?

Tags: java, sorting, lucene

I have a Lucene index where every document has several fields which contain numeric values. Now I would like to sort the search result on a weighted sum of this field.
For example:

```
field1=100
field2=002
field3=014
```

And the weighting function looks like:

```
f(d) = field1 * 0.5 + field2 * 1.4 + field3 * 1.8
```

The results should be ordered by `f(d)` where `d` represents the document. The sorting function should be non-static and could differ from search to search because the constant factors are influenced by the user who performs the search.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this or maybe an idea how to accomplish this goal in another way?

Comment: Are you building the Query object yourself or is it being generated via a QueryParser?

Comment: The Query is build manually not with the query parser.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try implementing a custom [ScoreDocComparator](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ScoreDocComparator.html). For example:

```
public class ScaledScoreDocComparator implements ScoreDocComparator {

    private int[][] values;
    private float[] scalars;

    public ScaledScoreDocComparator(IndexReader reader, String[] fields, float[] scalars) throws IOException {
        this.scalars = scalars;
        this.values = new int[fields.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            this.values[i] = FieldCache.DEFAULT.getInts(reader, fields[i]);
        }
    }

    protected float score(ScoreDoc scoreDoc) {
        int doc = scoreDoc.doc;

        float score = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            int value = values[i][doc];
            float scalar = scalars[i];
            score += (value * scalar);
        }
        return score;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ScoreDoc i, ScoreDoc j) {
        float iScore = score(i);
        float jScore = score(j);
        return Float.compare(iScore, jScore);
    }

    @Override
    public int sortType() {
        return SortField.CUSTOM;
    }

    @Override
    public Comparable<?> sortValue(ScoreDoc i) {
        float score = score(i);
        return Float.valueOf(score);
    }

}
```

Here is an example of `ScaledScoreDocComparator` in action. I believe it works in my test, but I encourage you to prove it against your data.

```
final String[] fields = new String[]{ "field1", "field2", "field3" };
final float[] scalars = new float[]{ 0.5f, 1.4f, 1.8f };

Sort sort = new Sort(
    new SortField(
        "",
        new SortComparatorSource() {
            public ScoreDocComparator newComparator(IndexReader reader, String fieldName) throws IOException {
                return new ScaledScoreDocComparator(reader, fields, scalars);
            }
        }
    )
);

IndexSearcher indexSearcher = ...;
Query query = ...;
Filter filter = ...; // can be null
int nDocs = 100;

TopFieldDocs topFieldDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, filter, nDocs, sort);
ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = topFieldDocs.scoreDocs;
```

### Bonus!

It appears that the Lucene developers are deprecating the `ScoreDocComparator` interface (it's currently deprecated in the Subversion repository). Here is an example of the `ScaledScoreDocComparator` modified to adhere to `ScoreDocComparator`'s successor, `FieldComparator`:

```
public class ScaledComparator extends FieldComparator {

    private String[] fields;
    private float[] scalars;
    private int[][] slotValues;
    private int[][] currentReaderValues;
    private int bottomSlot;

    public ScaledComparator(int numHits, String[] fields, float[] scalars) {
        this.fields = fields;
        this.scalars = scalars;

        this.slotValues = new int[this.fields.length][];
        for (int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < this.fields.length; fieldIndex++) {
            this.slotValues[fieldIndex] = new int[numHits];
        }

        this.currentReaderValues = new int[this.fields.length][];
    }

    protected float score(int[][] values, int secondaryIndex) {
        float score = 0;

        for (int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < fields.length; fieldIndex++) {
            int value = values[fieldIndex][secondaryIndex];
            float scalar = scalars[fieldIndex];
            score += (value * scalar);
        }

        return score;
    }

    protected float scoreSlot(int slot) {
        return score(slotValues, slot);
    }

    protected float scoreDoc(int doc) {
        return score(currentReaderValues, doc);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(int slot1, int slot2) {
        float score1 = scoreSlot(slot1);
        float score2 = scoreSlot(slot2);
        return Float.compare(score1, score2);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareBottom(int doc) throws IOException {
        float bottomScore = scoreSlot(bottomSlot);
        float docScore = scoreDoc(doc);
        return Float.compare(bottomScore, docScore);
    }

    @Override
    public void copy(int slot, int doc) throws IOException {
        for (int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < fields.length; fieldIndex++) {
            slotValues[fieldIndex][slot] = currentReaderValues[fieldIndex][doc];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setBottom(int slot) {
        bottomSlot = slot;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNextReader(IndexReader reader, int docBase, int numSlotsFull) throws IOException {
        for (int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < fields.length; fieldIndex++) {
            String field = fields[fieldIndex];
            currentReaderValues[fieldIndex] = FieldCache.DEFAULT.getInts(reader, field);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int sortType() {
        return SortField.CUSTOM;
    }

    @Override
    public Comparable<?> value(int slot) {
        float score = scoreSlot(slot);
        return Float.valueOf(score);
    }

}
```

Using this new class is very similar to the original, except that the definition of the `sort` object is a bit different:

```
final String[] fields = new String[]{ "field1", "field2", "field3" };
final float[] scalars = new float[]{ 0.5f, 1.4f, 1.8f };

Sort sort = new Sort(
    new SortField(
        "",
        new FieldComparatorSource() {
            public FieldComparator newComparator(String fieldname, int numHits, int sortPos, boolean reversed) throws IOException {
                return new ScaledComparator(numHits, fields, scalars);
            }
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: Adam, can you post an update version that is compatible with lucene 4.7? in the latest release setNextReader takes AtomicReaderContext and returns FieldComparator. appreciate the help

Comment: @SameehHarfoush you can find a new version compatible with lucene 4.10.1 in answer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708833/how-to-disable-default-scoring-boosting-in-hibernate-search-lucene/33638222.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking one way to do this would be to accept these as parameters to your sorting function:

number of fields, array of documents, list of weight factors(based on the number of fields)

Calculate the weighing function for each document, storing the result in a separate array in the same order as the document array. Then, perform any sort you wish (quick sort would probably be best), making sure you are sorting not just the f(d) array, but the document array as well. Return the sorted documents array and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own similarity class and override [idf(Term, Searcher)](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html#idf(org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Searcher)) method. 
In this method, you can return the score as follows.    if (term.field.equals("field1") {

```
    if (term.field.equals("field1") {
        score = 0.5 * Integer.parseInt(term.text());
    } else if (term.field.equals("field2") {
        score = 1.4 * Integer.parseInt(term.text());
    } // and so on
    return score;
```

When you execute the query, make sure it is on all the fields. That is query should look like

> field1:term field2:term field3:term

The final score will also add some weights based on the query normalization. But, that will not affect the relative ranking of the documents as per the equation given by you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper which holds the rating and is comparable. Something like:

```
public void sort(Datum[] data) {
   Rating[] ratings = new Rating[data.length];
   for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
     rating[i] = new Rating(data[i]);
   Arrays.sort(rating);
   for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
     data[i] = rating[i].datum;
}

class Rating implements Comparable<Datum> {
   final double rating;
   final Datum datum;

   public Rating(Datum datum) {
      this.datum = datum;
      rating = datum.field1 * 0.5 + datum.field2 * 1.4 + datum.field3 * 1.8
   }

   public int compareTo(Datum d) {
      return Double.compare(rating, d.rating);
   }
}
```